# Not able to connect Database from webhttp binding

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, wcf, webhttpbinding

In my ASP.NET 4.0 web application I have created a WCF service with webhttp binding (that service is part of the ASP.NET application and not a different project or solution).

The service works fine if run the application from Visual Studio but when hosted on IIS it gives error: HTTP 404. The service not found.

Could someone please help?

[image: Project Settings]

Thanks.

Further, the application is working fine when used with **HTTPS (with SSL)** but not with HTTP. Without SSL I am getting **HTTP Error 401** (authentication error)...

Comment: Yes Yeldar I am using Cassini web server which comes with Visual Studio. By project settings you mean web.config or else?

Comment: No, I mean contents of Web tab of project settings. Something like [this](https://mscblogs.blob.core.windows.net/media/gunnarpeipman/Media/vs2010sp1-use-iis-express-settings_64E0A170.png)

Comment: Attached the screenshot...however just an update I am publishing the site by Publish Web Site option of the project and the location is IIS Server.

Comment: Separate your WCF to your ASP.NET Project . It must have separate virtual directory.